# UWP app crashes when target detected

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp, vuforia

I need some help. I have an app that identifies a vuforia defined marker and adds an object over the marker when detected. This app runs in the unity editor and as an Android deployed version. The issues is that when I deploy it as an UWP app, is "crashes" once it detects the defined marker. No error message just closes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers, 
David

Comment: I believe for any one to be able to help you answer your question, you need to add more detail as to what you are doing. Include some code in your question where this `target` is being detected.

Comment: The target is a vuforia target. that is an image I have loaded up to vuforia and got the marker info for. This info is then added to Vuforias gameobject ("ImageTarget"). There is no code to show as it is all done in Unity Editor

Comment: You should still add more detail as your question mentions nothing about Vuforia except as a tag, which is why I asked about how you are getting `target`.

Comment: I edited the question. there is not much more detail I can say other than it is a simple AR application.